# How to tell Docker to pull latest image for "sub-image"?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Example from my PHP Dockerfile:

```
# Install composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
```

With that, I would expect to have the latest composer version in my container. But I have some old versions. When I do `docker images` I see that my `composer:latest` image is outdated:

```
composer                              latest                 8f2928e1f548   8 months ago     176MB
```

So what I do is:

```
docker-compose pull --include-deps
docker-compose up -d --build --remove-orphans
```

But, it only pulls the base images, not the ones I rely on via `--from`.

Is there some option I oversee? Or should I just require some specific version like `:2.0.13`? I've seen some blog posts about the `:latest` tag being not what it suggests to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you should understand that `--include-deps` works only for images that you set in the `depends_on` directive. Not for multistage.

For your case, you probably should build your image without cache.

`docker build --pull --no-cache --tag myimage:version .` before push to a repository
or if you use build in your docker-compose file

`docker-compose build --no-cache --pull`

Comment: Thank you, `docker-compose build --pull --no-cache` solved the issue. Now of course it takes longer, but anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `:latest` tag is that it doesn't really mean that you are pulling the last update of that image, just the one they tagged as `:latest`.

Many times it's some versions outdated but it may be the last stable image, so it's not a bad idea to use latest if you don't have any preference on the version of the image.

Comment: Yes, but in the concrete example of Composer their `:latest` is actually the latest, but my local `:latest` tagged image is old. The problem is the pull command doesn't update it if it's not directly defined as a service in the docker-compose.yml but relied on via `COPY --from`. So I would need something like a "recursive" pull.

Comment: I think there is an option called ´upgrade´ but if you dont have any container attached to the image I would just delete the image and pull it again with the new true `:latest`

Comment: Hm, I don't see such an option. And yes of course I can manually remove the old image and pull the newest, but working in a team, I want to have it as simple as possible without any manual steps so that everyone has always the same setup.

Comment: Then if you are working with a team you should use version tags so it never gets messy to identify the version you are working with. `:latest` isn's a good idea because of the point you are making with this post.

Comment: Yes, I see :latest has multiple layers of problems. 1: it can be "cached" like in my case and 2: even if it's not cached it can still be outdated if the maintainer doesn't properly update it, so :latest doesn't necessarily mean it's really the latest. Thank you also for your input!